# Unbranded Chinese USB WiFi adapter drivers for Windows XP

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp, usb, drivers

[image: Screenshot]

I used this adapter for more than 4 weeks without any issues on Windows 7. I switched to Windows XP about 2 hours ago, installed all the drivers I had, and now WiFi isn't working. Can anyone provide a driver for this unbranded Chinese WiFi adapter?

1. I checked the adapter on the Windows 7 PC and it worked perfectly without any drivers
2. The adapter supports Windows 98 to Windows 10

Comment: Try opening Device Manager (typing devmgmt.msc in Run) and pressig the search button at the top

Comment: It ask for drivers but i don't have any :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hardware ID "`usb\vid_148f&pid_7601`" means that you use an TP-LINK Wireless USB Adapter.

Try the [XP driver from here](http://devid.info/63489).

Comment: Will try and let you know

Comment: OMG! That's worked without any issue

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time on my problem! Driver you provided totally worked without any issue

Comment: ok, click on the green button to close the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work